# How to check if specific field has specific value in MongoDB using Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, database, mongodb

This is my structure. Let's say I have got a bunch of these objects in my collection. I want to search for value for the field `twitterId`. In this case, let's say I want to check whether `102030`  value exists in any of my `twitterId` fields? How can I build this query in Java Spring?

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5f4edc8f0edc9e79dcd58cb4"), 
"twitterId" : "102030", 
"fullName" : "Elon Musk", 
"followers" : [ ], 
"_class" : "xxxx.yyyyy.model.User" 
}
```

Comment: There are many ways you can write a query using Spring Data MongoDB. One way is to query using the `MongoTemplate#exists` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a repository which will do the search. Create something like this:

```
@Repository("user")
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    
    public Optional<User> findOneByTwitterId(String twitterId);

}
```

Then you can check if there is a value in the optional.

Of course they are plenty of other solution. You can also write a query to count how many users have this twitter id

Comment: FYI : Since you extends MongoRepostiry you don't need to use `@Repostitory`, and the type of `_id` is `ObjectId`. So  MongoRepository<User, ObjectId>.  And no need to use findOneBy.... just use `existsByTwitterId(String twitterId)`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Repository("user")
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    @Query (value = " {'twitterId': ?0} ", count = true)
    public int findByTwitterId(String twitterId);
}
```

Comment: Basically the same answer as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705331/how-to-check-if-specific-field-has-specific-value-in-mongodb-using-java-spring/63705537#63705537) but with an extra annotation. Perhaps you can edit your answer and post an explanation of what that annotation does?